# Mailchimp in React

Tags: react, npm

import MailchimpSubscribe from "react-mailchimp-subscribe";
import { Newsletter } from "./Newsletter";

export const MailchimpForm = () => {
const postUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL}?u=${process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_U}&id=${process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_ID}`;

return (
<>
<MailchimpSubscribe
url={postUrl}
render={({ subscribe, status, message }) => (
<Newsletter
status={status}
message={message}
onValidated={formData => subscribe(formData)}
/>
)}
/>
</>
)
}

//Error message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

**Hey guys!
I'm embarking on learning react, and I would like to understand why this error is happening, saying that the process is undefined.
I have already created my config .env file

//.env file content:**

REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL =  ""
REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_U = ""
REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_ID = ""